# How to serve angularjs app accessible to other devices on LAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, mobile

I have angular js running on a windows 7 machine. 'node server' gets me running on localhost:3000 fine.

localhost is 10.0.1.24 on my LAN.

For http://coenraets.org/apps/angular-directory/#/employees, 10.0.1.24:3000 runs a crippled version of the app. It would seem the routing isn't working.

I need to be able to run as 10.0.1.24:3000 so I can access the app from mobile devices on the LAN.

I'm looking learn a MV* framework and rewrite old jquery-mobile apps.

Is there a node directive like meteor's ROOT_URL=? Or is there another way?

Comment: Go to 10.0.1.24:3000 from another computer and open the dev tools.  What errors do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [coenraets](http://coenraets.org/apps/angular-directory/#/employees) app I was trying to run specified localhost in its rest-services.js script.

By changing localhost to 10.0.1.24 everything works

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.restServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Employee', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('http://10.0.1.24:3000/employees/:employeeId', {});
        }])

    .factory('Report', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('http://10.0.1.24:3000/employees/:employeeId/reports', {});
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your question is missing some important details here.

> I have angular js, node and mongo running... I'm looking learn a MV* framework... It would seem the routing isn't working.

So Node.js is *very* low level and does not really have any form of routing baked in. MongoDB has only a limited HTTP admin UI and is clearly not designed for this type of activity either.

If you need something that does routing and data access, there are tools like Meteor or Geddy or Sails (*or many more*) that connect your web server to your Database and output JSON results.

> I need to be able to run as 10.0.1.24:3000...  `node server` gets me running on localhost:3000 fine.

Your own comments contradict each other.

**What is your specific problem?**

Comment: I want to see how the app looks on a mobile browser. I have and ipad and android phone on the LAN. It is something that is a no-brainer on a LAMP stack.